# Web page is meant to return a number based an answer but only ever returns null?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-core

This piece of code is meant to return a number based on answer running in SQL Server. We already have answers populated however the webpage only ever returns null (0) when it should return for example (5).

Can anyone help?

```
public IActionResult OnPost(IList<Selection> selections)
{
    selections = selections;
    byte j = 0;

    for (byte i = 0; i < selections.Count; i++)
    {
        if (selections[i].Answer != 80)
        {
            Selected[j] = selections[i].Answer;
            j++;
        }
    }

    return Page();
}
```

The other part of the code that posts the number to the page is listed below.

```
<form method="POST">
    @{IList<Selection> selections = Model.Selections;}
    @foreach (var Que in Model.Questions)
    {
        <b>@Que.Text</b>
        <br />
        @for (byte i = 0; i < Model.Answers.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Que.ID == Model.Answers[i].QuestionID)
            {
                <div style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    <label asp-for="@selections[i].Answer">@Model.Answers[i].Text</label>

                    <input type="radio" value="@Model.Answers[i].ID" name="@Que.ID" asp-for="@selections[i].Answer" />
                </div>
            }
        }
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    }
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" value="@selections" asp-for="@selections">
    <input type="submit" asp-route-selections="@selections" />
</form>
```

Comment: This code returns `Page()`.  It doesn't do anything with the results of its calculations.  (Where is `Selected` even defined?)  Where/how specifically are you observing the result you describe?  As an aside, this line is entirely pointless: `selections = selections;`

Comment: Have you debugged this at all?  What happens when you step into `Page()`?

Comment: It should just return a blank webpage. I have .cshtml page setup that it should return to.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What are you actually trying to do here? You say the 'page is meant to return a number' in the question, and 'it should return a blank webpage' in one of your comments. Those are 2 different things. Is the *method* `OnPost` supposed to return a number? If so, it is not. It is returning a `Page`. Is the returned `Page` supposed to have the number on it somewhere? Well, how could it, the `Page` is never told what the number should be. I think you need to step back and think about what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I will post more tomorrow as I'm not at my PC. I have the page pulling the number but it always returns 0 or null. Should I post the code on the page?

Comment: @ReeceHewitt: *"I have the page pulling the number but it always returns 0 or null."* - That code isn't present in the question.  What debugging have you done to conclude that the code you're showing us *must* be the problem?  When you debug the code you're showing us, which specific operation performs an unexpected result?  If the code you're showing us *doesn't* observably produce an unexpected result, then what code *does*?  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem and indicate specifically where you observe the problem.

Comment: I've posted the second part of the code that is actually meant to show a number. Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a Page(). You should be returning the value you want wrapped in an IActionResult

```
public IActionResult OnPost(IList<Selection> selections)
{
     byte j = 0;
     for (byte i = 0; i < selections.Count; i++)
     {
          if (selections[i].Answer != 80)
          {
               Selected[j] = selections[i].Answer;
               j++;
          }
     }

     return Ok(Selected);
}
```

Comment: I tried this method. Visual Stuido complains about the 'Ok' section.

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0103?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0103)

Comment: You might need to import the relevant packages. Try clicking the error and press `Ctrl + .` That should bring up a small window with a possible resolution in it. Then simply press enter.

Comment: Just tried using that method it just import a private class below the method. In that class it just throws a "Not Implemented" exception & closes the browser.